# Google foo.bar failing all test cases but working in python IDE

Tags: python

So I'm doing the foo.bar challenge, and I've got code in python that outputs the required answers. I know for a fact that for at least the first two test cases my output matches their output but it still fails all of them. I assumed it could be because its running in python 2.7.13 so I found an online sandbox that runs that version of python but my code still outputs the required output there too. I've tried using the print function to output the results, I've tried formatting the results as lists and arrays but none of this worked. The question is below:

> ## Doomsday Fuel
>
> Making fuel for the LAMBCHOP's reactor core is a tricky process
> because of the exotic matter involved. It starts as raw ore, then
> during processing, begins randomly changing between forms, eventually
> reaching a stable form. There may be multiple stable forms that a
> sample could ultimately reach, not all of which are useful as fuel.
>
> Commander Lambda has tasked you to help the scientists increase fuel
> creation efficiency by predicting the end state of a given ore sample.
> You have carefully studied the different structures that the ore can
> take and which transitions it undergoes. It appears that, while
> random, the probability of each structure transforming is fixed. That
> is, each time the ore is in 1 state, it has the same probabilities of
> entering the next state (which might be the same state).  You have
> recorded the observed transitions in a matrix. The others in the lab
> have hypothesized more exotic forms that the ore can become, but you
> haven't seen all of them.
>
> Write a function solution(m) that takes an array of array of
> nonnegative ints representing how many times that state has gone to
> the next state and return an array of ints for each terminal state
> giving the exact probabilities of each terminal state, represented as
> the numerator for each state, then the denominator for all of them at
> the end and in simplest form. The matrix is at most 10 by 10. It is
> guaranteed that no matter which state the ore is in, there is a path
> from that state to a terminal state. That is, the processing will
> always eventually end in a stable state. The ore starts in state 0.
> The denominator will fit within a signed 32-bit integer during the
> calculation, as long as the fraction is simplified regularly.
>
> For example, consider the matrix m: [   [0,1,0,0,0,1],  # s0, the
> initial state, goes to s1 and s5 with equal probability
> [4,0,0,3,2,0],  # s1 can become s0, s3, or s4, but with different
> probabilities   [0,0,0,0,0,0],  # s2 is terminal, and unreachable
> (never observed in practice)   [0,0,0,0,0,0],  # s3 is terminal
> [0,0,0,0,0,0],  # s4 is terminal   [0,0,0,0,0,0],  # s5 is terminal ]
> So, we can consider different paths to terminal states, such as: s0 ->
> s1 -> s3 s0 -> s1 -> s0 -> s1 -> s0 -> s1 -> s4 s0 -> s1 -> s0 -> s5
> Tracing the probabilities of each, we find that s2 has probability 0
> s3 has probability 3/14 s4 has probability 1/7 s5 has probability 9/14
> So, putting that together, and making a common denominator, gives an
> answer in the form of [s2.numerator, s3.numerator, s4.numerator,
> s5.numerator, denominator] which is [0, 3, 2, 9, 14].
>
> ## Languages
>
> To provide a Java solution, edit Solution.java To provide a Python
> solution, edit solution.py
>
> Test cases
> ========== Your code should pass the following test cases. Note that it may also be run against hidden test cases not shown here.
>
> -- Java cases -- Input: Solution.solution({{0, 2, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 3, 4}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0,0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}) Output:
> [7, 6, 8, 21]
>
> Input: Solution.solution({{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {4, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0}, {0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0}}) Output:
> [0, 3, 2, 9, 14]
>
> -- Python cases -- Input: solution.solution([[0, 2, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 3, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0,0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]) Output:
> [7, 6, 8, 21]
>
> Input: solution.solution([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [4, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0], [0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0]]) Output:
> [0, 3, 2, 9, 14]

my code is below:

```
import numpy as np
from fractions import Fraction
from math import gcd


def solution(M):
    height = (len(M))
    length = (len(M[0]))
    M = np.array(M)
    AB = []
    
    #Find B
    for i in range(0, height):
        #if B = 1
        if (sum(M[:,0])) == 0:
            sumB = 1 
        if(M[i,0]) != 0:
            B1 = Fraction((M[i,0]), (sum(M[i])))
            B2 = Fraction((M[0,i]), (sum(M[0])))
            B = B1 * B2

            #Find sum(B) to infinity
            sumB = (1/(1-B))

    #Find A
    boolean2 = 0
    count = 0
    index = []
    for i in range (0, height):
        if sum(M[i]) == 0:
            if boolean2 == 0:
                terminalstart = i
            boolean = 0
            boolean2 = 1
            for j in range(0, height):
                #if there is no A
                if j==height-1 and boolean == 0:
                    index.append(i-terminalstart)
                    count +=1
                if (M[j,i]) != 0:
                    boolean = 1
                    A1 = Fraction((M[j,i]), (sum(M[j])))
                    A = A1
                    if j!=0:
                        A2 = Fraction((M[0,j]), (sum(M[0])))
                        A = A1 * A2
                    
                    #Find AB
                    AB.append(A*sumB)

    #Find common denominators
    x = []
    y = []
    for i in range (0,len(AB)):
        x.append(AB[i].denominator)
    lcm = 1
    #change numerators to fit
    for i in x:
        lcm = lcm*i//gcd(lcm, i)
    for i in range (0, len(AB)):
        z = (lcm) / x[i]
        #
        z = float(z)
        #
        y.append(int((AB[i].numerator)*z))
        
    #insert 0s
    for i in range (0, count):
        y.insert(index[i], 0)

    #insert denominator
    y.append(lcm)
    return y
```

So the code and the questions are basically irrelevant, the main point is, my output (y) is exactly the same as the output in the examples, but when it runs in foo.bar it fails. To test it I used a code that simply returned the desired output in foo.bar and it worked for the test case that had this output:

```
def solution(M):
    y = [0, 3, 2, 9, 14]
    return y
```

So I know that since my code gets to the exact same array and data type for y in the python IDE it should work in google foo.bar, but for some reason its not. Any help would be greatly appreciated

edit:
I found a code online that works:

```
import numpy as np

# Returns indexes of active & terminal states
def detect_states(matrix):
    active, terminal = [], []
    for rowN, row in enumerate(matrix):
        (active if sum(row) else terminal).append(rowN)
    return(active,terminal)

# Convert elements of array in simplest form
def simplest_form(B):
    B = B.round().astype(int).A1                   # np.matrix --> np.array
    gcd = np.gcd.reduce(B)
    B = np.append(B, B.sum())                      # append the common denom
    return (B / gcd).astype(int)

# Finds solution by calculating Absorbing probabilities
def solution(m):
    active, terminal = detect_states(m)
    if 0 in terminal:                              # special case when s0 is terminal
        return [1] + [0]*len(terminal[1:]) + [1]
    m = np.matrix(m, dtype=float)[active, :]       # list --> np.matrix (active states only)
    comm_denom = np.prod(m.sum(1))                 # product of sum of all active rows (used later)
    P = m / m.sum(1)                               # divide by sum of row to convert to probability matrix
    Q, R = P[:, active], P[:, terminal]            # separate Q & R
    I = np.identity(len(Q))
    N = (I - Q) ** (-1)                            # calc fundamental matrix
    B = N[0] * R * comm_denom / np.linalg.det(N)   # get absorbing probs & get them close to some integer
    return simplest_form(B)
```

When I compared the final answer from this working code to mine by adding the lines:

```
print(simplest_form(B))
print(type(simplest_form(B))
```

this is what I got

```
[ 0  3  2  9 14]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
array([ 0,  3,  2,  9, 14])
```

When I added the lines

```
y = np.asarray(y)
print(y)
print(type(y))
```

to my code this is what I got:

```
[ 0  3  2  9 14]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
array([ 0,  3,  2,  9, 14])
```

when they were both running the same test input. These are the exact same but for some reason mine doesn't work on foo.bar but his does. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you know whether foo.bar is running Python2 or Python3?  It's worth noting that / means something different when applied to two integers between P2 and P3.  `from __future__ import division` might help if that's the problem.

Comment: @FrankYellin Thanks for the advice, It is running python 2.7.13, my IDE is running 3.10.2. I tried adding that line but it didn't work. Which line are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the

```
math.gcd(x, y)
```

function is not allowed in python 2. I just rewrote it as this:

```
def grcd(x, y):
    if x >= y:
        big = x
        small = y
    else:
        big = y
        small = x
    bool1 = 1
    for i in range(1, big+1):
        while bool1 == 1:
            if big % small == 0:
                greatest = small
                bool1 = 0
            small-= 1
    return greatest
```

Comment: Dang.  I just discovered that and came back to this post to tell you.

You can use `fractions.gcd` instead of writing your own.